# openoffice calc button mouse over event cursor change

Tags: macros, openoffice-calc

I have created an OpenOffice Calc spreadsheet and I have inserted a button into it. I can successfully call a macro with the button. I want to have a cursor hand when I mouse-over the button.

First, I switched to 'Design' mode, then I right-clicked on my button, and using the pop-up menu which appears, I selected the 'Events' tab. Then I clicked on the 'Mouse inside' dot dot dot button. In the 'Assign action' window that popped up, I clicked on the 'Macro..' button. I then got the 'Macro Selector' pop-up window, where I choose the 'OpenOffice Macros' folder in the left side pane. I expanded 'Tools'>'ModuleControls' from that 'Library' pane and then selected 'SwitchMousePointer' from the right side 'Macro name' pane, then clicked the 'Ok' 'Ok' buttons.

But now when I hover the mouse cursor over my button I get an OpenOffice Error window popping up "A Scripting Framework error occurred while running the Basic script Tools.ModuleControls.SwitchMousePointer."

I've very little OO experience but I have not found what I want here or on the OO Forum site. I would be very grateful to get some help, thanks, Nige.

Answer (score 0):

The SwitchMousePointer needs attributes (oWindowPeer as Object, bDoEnable as Boolean). So you can't simply assign it to a event. And it will not do what you think.

You should better write you own Sub to change the Pointer. Also there is no need to do this on every mouse event. It should be done once on sheet activate for example.

For a introduce in OpenOffice.org BASIC Programming see https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide. And you will need a debugging tool, if you want to program your own BASIC macros. Therefore see especially: https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide/UNO_Tools

Assuming on the sheet is a button named "Push Button 1" then:

```
Sub ChangeMousePointer
    oController = ThisComponent.CurrentController
    oButtonModel = oController.ActiveSheet.DrawPage.Forms(0).getByName("Push Button 1")
    oButtonControl = oController.getControl(oButtonModel)
    oWindowPointer = CreateUnoService("com.sun.star.awt.Pointer")
    oWindowPointer.SetType(com.sun.star.awt.SystemPointer.HAND)
    oButtonControl.Peer.setPointer(oWindowPointer)
End Sub
```

And assign this to the sheet event Activate Document.
Right click the sheet tab and select Sheet Events from the context menu. Then:
[image]

If, and only if, the button is on Sheets(0) then the sheet event Activate Document not occurs while opening the document and this sheet is in front. In this case we have to call the Sub ChangeMousePointer also on document event Open Document.

```
Sub Document_Open
    oController = ThisComponent.CurrentController 
    oSheet = oController.ActiveSheet
    if oSheet.Name = ThisComponent.Sheets(0).Name then 
        if oController.ActiveSheet.DrawPage.Forms.Count > 0 then
            if oController.ActiveSheet.DrawPage.Forms(0).hasByName("Push Button 1") then
               call ChangeMousePointer
            end if
        end if
    end if
End Sub
```

To assign the macro to the document event Open Document select Tools - Customize from the menu and:
[image]

Comment: Hi Axel, many thanks for your good answer. I have tried it and it works for me. Except that it only works after I select another sheet, e.g. Sheet 2 then select Sheet 1 again. I have the button on Sheet 1. Until I have reloaded the sheet the pointer does not change. Have I missed something here? Thanks,  Nige.

Comment: Sorry, works for me with Openoffice 4.1.1 and Libreoffice 4.2.6.2. Which version you have?

Comment: AOO 4.1.1 under Windows 8 When you first open the spreadsheet does it work without selecting a sheet tab?

Comment: Hm, wait, directly after you have created the macro and assigned it to the event "Activate Document", it is surely so that you have to change the selected sheet to force the event. But you also can save the file and reopen and the event will also occur. And from this on it will working every time you open the file.

Comment: No, when I first open the spreadsheet the macro does not take effect. It only works when I select another sheet and then select the button sheet (1) again. I have just created another new spreadsheet and added a button and then your recommended solution; to check I have not done anything different. It is the same.

Comment: Yes, you are right. With the first sheet in front while opening the calc document the sheet event Activate Document not occurs. See my edited answer. But the better approach would be to have the button not in the first sheet. Because even if every other sheet is in front while opening, the event will occur.

Comment: Thank you Axel, that works for me now. I much appreciate your help. Would it be easy to expand the solution to make it work for all buttons in any sheet?